# extract pure text strings from php scripts for translation

Tags: php

I have project which contains bigger amount of php files. Former programmer wrote everything (texts) in english in source files together with html code and I need to make translation now. Go manually file by file and extract all texts to one lanugage file is huge pain. Is there any free tool please to extract and convert all text to e.g. variables in source files and produce just one big file with text variables to simple translation?

many thanks.

P.S. I would like to automatize this work rather than manually do it file-by-file.

Examples of code in php files:

```
<?php 
echo "Hi back, " . $user;
?>

<center class="title">No list(s) available.</center>

<tr id="exp<?php echo $r; ?>" class="me"  onmouseover="dis('<?php echo $u; ?>');"> <td>This is new statement</td></tr>
```

Comment: can you share any example

Comment: Is that file are csv or excel ? can you share more detail..?

Comment: there is no csv/excel file. I added examples.

Comment: I think there is no way a program could tell when a text block starts and ends properly. The real question is, why are you required to refactor a whole project this way. It's a big task where all developers are involved and your boss must be planning time accordingly. This is not a one-people fix it job.

Comment: so you need "No list(s) available" and "This is new statement" to be extracted ? something like this ?

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa, yes, exactly. I would like to use some kind of program to extract all of these text, then I will be able to translate it. Then program should rewrite them (or the best way would be to store them in separate language file, where I can easily translate them as per need). But if program just rewrite them in their original location, this is perfectly acceptable

Comment: Honestly if that's an example of the level of code you need to deal with, and you're just supposed to provide a translation. The time it will take for you to try to extract, translate and re-insert all the hard-coded English strings... is not much different from refactoring the whole lot with actual language support. Bonus problems for writing a parser for translation preprocessing: 1. Extracting from a mix of PHP & HTML, 2. Interpolated variables, probably in several different styles. I haven't come across a tool for this, one could certainly produce such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

this function is gonna help you in some cases and it returns the plain text between **>** and **<**
before you start you need to replace

> ' (quotation)

with

> \' (backslash quotation)

```
$text = '
<?php 
echo "Hi back, " . $user;
?>

<center class="title">No list(s) available.</center>

<tr id="exp<?php echo $r; ?>" class="me"  onmouseover="dis(\'<?php echo $u; ?>\');"> <td>This is new statement</td></tr>
';
```

the function is:

```
function getSentences($string){
    $arr = array();
    $parts = explode(">", $string);
    if(count($parts) > 2){
        $pattern = "/\>(.*?)</";
        foreach($parts as $part){
            $part = ">" . $part;
            preg_match($pattern, trim($part), $matches);
            if(!empty($matches[1]) AND $matches[1] != " "){
                if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/', $matches[1])){
                    $arr[] = $matches[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $pattern = "/\>(.*?)</";
        preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
        $arr[] = $matches[1];
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

and call the function by :

```
print_r(getSentences($text));
```

the output will be something like this:

```
 Array ( [0] => No list(s) available. [1] => This is new statement )
```